# How do I make linked Word and Excel documents portable?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

We have some Report template documents in Word that are linked to template excel documents with various OLE linked objects from Excel to Word.

Since OLE uses absolute paths vs. relative, copy pasting the two documents to another location (or even moving them) breaks the OLE links.

So, what's the best way to facilitate moving the documents to another location AND moving the Word template and being able to link it to another Excel document in the new location?

I've searched through numerous sites and found some solutions for technical people:

1. http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html
2. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/making-excel-links-in-word-portable-ie-relative/8f67c68e-6406-4ef2-9b97-4d96c43dcb2c,

BUT this needs to be easy enough for non-technical people to use.

I would like to be able to copy and paste BOTH documents (the Word template AND the linked Excel template) to a new location and have them work the same way they did in the original location.

I would also like to be able to copy just the Word template to a new location and link it to an Excel template in that new location.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a solution to a problem that I had a difficult time finding an answer for, so I wanted to share what ended up working for me.

The code looks in the working directory of the word document, finds the first excel document (I only have 1 excel file per folder in my job, so this setup works for me), and changes the source of all OLE objects in the word document to match the excel document, which makes it possible to create a word/excel template pair and move them to different locations.

*NOTE: I've used Windows sepecific objects/functions for I/O, i.e. MyFile, MyFSO, MyFolder... etc., but I don't think it would be terribly difficult to make the I/O platform agnostic.

**NOTE: I also haven't really added any error checking as it's a quick and dirty macro that's used internally to facilitate portability AND I've never used vba before, so garbage cleanup etc. was a just kind of thrown in there, if there's a way to refactor everything and clean it up, please let me know.

```
Sub UpdateWordLinks()

Dim newFilePath As Variant
Dim excelDocs As Variant
Dim range As Word.range
Dim shape As shape
Dim section As Word.section

excelDocs = GetFileNamesbyExt(ThisDocument.Path, ".xlsx")

'The new file path as a string (the text to replace with)'
newFilePath = ThisDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & excelDocs(1)

Call updateFields(ThisDocument.fields, newFilePath)

For Each section In ThisDocument.Sections

    Call updateHeaderFooterLinks(section.headers, newFilePath)

    Call updateHeaderFooterLinks(section.Footers, newFilePath)

Next

'Update the links
ThisDocument.fields.Update

Set newFilePath = Nothing
Set excelDocs(1) = Nothing
Set excelDocs = Nothing
Set range = Nothing
Set shape = Nothing
Set section = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetFileNamesbyExt(ByVal FolderPath As String, FileExt As String) As Variant

    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyFile As Object
    Dim MyFSO As Object
    Dim MyFolder As Object
    Dim MyFiles As Object
    Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files
    ReDim Result(1 To MyFiles.count)
    i = 1
    For Each MyFile In MyFiles
        If InStr(1, MyFile.Name, FileExt) <> 0 Then
            Result(i) = MyFile.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next MyFile
    ReDim Preserve Result(1 To i - 1)

    GetFileNamesbyExt = Result

    Set MyFile = Nothing
    Set MyFSO = Nothing
    Set MyFolder = Nothing
    Set MyFiles = Nothing

End Function

Function updateHeaderFooterLinks(headersFooters As headersFooters, newFilePath As Variant)

    Dim headerFooter As Word.headerFooter

    For Each headerFooter In headersFooters

        Call updateFields(headerFooter.range.fields, newFilePath)

    Next

    Set headerFooter = Nothing

End Function

Function updateFields(fields As fields, newFilePath As Variant)

    Dim field As field
    Dim oldFilePath As Variant

    For Each field In fields

        If field.Type = wdFieldLink Then

            oldFilePath = field.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

            field.Code.Text = Replace(field.Code.Text, _
            Replace(oldFilePath, "\", "\\"), _
            Replace(newFilePath, "\", "\\"))

        End If

    Next

    Set field = Nothing
    Set oldFilePath = Nothing

End Function
```

It works for me by allowing me to copy paste either both a word and excel file together to a new location and run the macro, or by allowing me to copy paste the word document only and run the macro to link it to an excel doc in the new location.

**I should also note that I only needed to look in the body and header/footer stories for the links we use, so this code is not as robust as it could be, but I don' think it would be too tough to add another loop or two to cover off any missing stories

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a way to create portable links between Excel and Word, our Excel-to-Word Document Automation Add-in may help. Unlike native linking through Office you can: rename files, copy/paste and reorganize content, share the linked files, etc. The same Excel document can update multiple destination Word and/or PowerPoint report templates. You only need to set up the links once and they can be updated numerous times. I hope this helps, you can find out more at https://analysisplace.com/Document-Automation

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "only need to set up the links once..."

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you.  With our add-in you set up links in your Excel workbook and Word/PowerPoint documents. Once the links are set up in Excel and Word/PowerPoint you can update your documents.  The links only need to be set up once for each document. Here's a quick youtube video that shows how the add-in works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kt9u_7MFn9s